# JPA : Use of list in where clause and Case statement together - Is there a way to loop through?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am using JPA-Hibernate in our application and I am working with a query like :

```
@Query(
value = "ReportDTO(report) FROM Report report " +
    "JOIN p.clientFile cf " +
    "JOIN cf.client cl " +
    "WHERE report.active = TRUE " +
    "AND :companyKey = CASE WHEN report.companyKey IS NOT NULL " +
        "THEN report.companyKey " +
        "ELSE cl.companyKey " +
        "END " +
    "ORDER BY report.publishedDate DESC",
countQuery = “..”
)
@NonNull
Page<TagReportDTO> findAll(@NonNull Pageable pageable, @Param("companyKey") String companyKey);
```

when the **"companyKey"** was a **single** value, it worked. Now, I need to change this findAll method to accept a **list of company keys**. So it should like like ( after the change) :

```
@NonNull
Page<TagReportDTO> findAll(@NonNull Pageable pageable, @Param("companyKeys") List<String> companyKeys);
```

Now I am getting hard time to accommodate the **list of objects or **companyKeys** (instead of :**companyKey**)** in the query where the the case statement will be applicable to each item in the list. Is there a way I can loop through ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using IN operator? Like this:

```
"AND (CASE WHEN report.companyKey IS NOT NULL " +
"THEN report.companyKey " +
"ELSE cl.companyKey " +
"END) IN :companyKeys "
```